# Why font-awesome does not work on web and work in localhost?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, font-awesome

Why font-awesome works on localhost but not on web ?

Help  Please!!

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@v=3.0.1');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff@v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf@v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Have you check the case in file names, Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: yes i checked it. i'm using windows server

Comment: Are you sure that you have uploaded the font awesome files?

Comment: i am very sure about it

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix to this issue from [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/374): 
It was answered by someone named Thorst about halfway down the page.

Saved me a ton of frustration!

In case the link goes stale->

> change font-awesome.css
>
> From:

```
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
 url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
 url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
```

> To:

```
 src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')
 format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff')
 format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf')
 format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')
 format('svg');
```

*Note: the format for the eot is what was changed.

Answer (score 1):

If your font-awesome files are on a different server than your web page, you may be getting a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error in your browser.  You can either use the MaxCDN server or modify your server (that provides the font-awesome files) to include a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header with the font files.  See my answer for [Font Awesome icons not showing in Chrome, a MaxCDN related Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393857/584846)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the use of `@` signs like that. Try using question marks in their place:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

On line 4, I've also also swapped the order of `#iefix` and `v=3.0.1`, and removed the `&`.