# Facebook like & CORS errors when loading font awesome from bootstrap's cdn

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, cors

### Setup:

We've implemented the following fix on our server based on this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125030/font-awesome-icons-not-showing-in-chrome-a-maxcdn-related-cross-origin-resource):

```
# ALLOW CROSS DOMAIN FONTS
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

We also have a Facebook like button on the site that is implemented with an AppID.

---

### Issue:

In DEV tools, we see the following three errors (2 SHA-1 errors and a CORS error):

1. This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use
   certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions
   stronger than SHA-1 = 7r8gQb8MIqE.js
2. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0.
   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
   enabling CORS. fontawesome-webfont.woff
3. This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use
   certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions
   stronger than SHA-1 = like.php

---

#### If we comment out the the Facebook like button, we don't see any of these errors.

---

### Question:

Does anyone know if the Facbook like button SHA-1 error is triggering the CORS error and does anyone know how to fix this situation?

---

### Update – tried MDN javascript but no change:

Have tried fixing this using javascript as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

But I don't fully understand what I'm doing and after clearing the cache etc I'm not seeing the header return of: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

This is what I tried:

```
<script>
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
  var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/';

  function callOtherDomain() {
    if(invocation) {
      invocation.open('GET', url, true);
      invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
      invocation.send();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So have tried using javascript as noted here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS and have updated the question.

Comment: In Firefox, I am getting the SHA1 error with the Facebook `like.php` script (but not the CORS error).