# Moving from development to production and FA icons are now squares

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors, font-awesome

[Development](http://webhost1.blackrhinoconsulting.com/blackrhinounion)

[Production](http://blackrhinounion.com)

I've read a ton of other posts, and 99% of them boil down to path issues. But if you look at my site you can see that it is properly loading the icon file:

Request URL:http://www.blackrhinounion.com/wp-content/themes/Centum/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

So I'm thinking something else is the culprit here?

(Edit) Attempted in .htaccess:

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

And it still didn't fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font Awesome icons not showing in Chrome, a MaxCDN related Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125030/font-awesome-icons-not-showing-in-chrome-a-maxcdn-related-cross-origin-resource)

Comment: This is a CORS issue with the following error: `Font from origin 'http://www.blackrhinounion.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://blackrhinounion.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

WP_SITEURL had a www in it, while the WP_HOME didn't. That caused the Cross-Origin issue, removing the www fixed everything.